# Mesh inside soft body - Mesh Deform not working

Tags: mesh, soft-body, artifacts

I am trying to make a mesh inside a soft body following this post:
[make soft bodies stay inside another soft body](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78955/make-soft-bodies-stay-inside-another-soft-body)

It creates artifacts when it moves, and i dont know what the problem is :

[image: Animated]

Comment: Please provide more info - it’s not clear what’s going on there. An animation showing it in action would be good, or upload your blend.

Comment: OK, i added a gif

Comment: Is the highlighted object the softbody or it is the rigid body container within? If it's the softbody then it looks like you have some vertices pinned to the goal. If it's the rigid body then it looks like the MeshDeform isn't working properly - did you edit the mesh after applying the MeshDeform or do those problem vertices reside *outside* of the MeshDeform container?

Comment: It is the rigid body, a made a subdivision, but I unbind it and bind it again

Comment: The subdivide must have resulted in some vertices lying outside the MeshDeform container. You’ll need to move them inside and then rebind - either by identifying them individually and moving them or you might get away with simply scaling the whole mesh down a bit and apply scale before rebinding.

Comment: Some, vertices where outside, this is the problem, i will do it with sculp.Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. I've edited the question and added an answer to hopefully help anyone else with the same problem in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the Mesh Deform modifier. The Mesh Deform only acts on those vertices that are within the Container mesh. In your case you have applied a subdivision surface modifier and this has resulted in some vertices that are outside the container mesh. This means that those vertices are not deformed to follow the softbody simulation and so they are left behind.

To resolve the issue, identify the vertices that are outside and move them within the container and re-bind the Mesh Deform modifier.