# soft body simulation Object contains another Object

Tags: soft-body

I would like to simulate soft objects, where an object with certain physical properties contains another object with different physical properties. Think of a t-shirt wrapped by a plastic bag.
The problem is, that these two objects don't interact with each other, they don't collide, even if I active collision on both (same collision group). The object keeps moving out of the bag.

What I have done so far:

- The pastic bag is a hollow object. (soft body active, collision active)
- the T-shirt is placed inside the bag (soft body active, collision active)

The soft body simulation of the objects works as expected, but the inner object moves out of the outer object, that's the main problem.

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/81992/29586