# Soft Bodies Merge Together During Animation

Tags: physics, collision, soft-body

I am trying to get some soft body balls to tumble around in a rotating cube (like a square washing machine). Each time I try and animate, it's like all the soft bodies merge together into one blob. I'm assuming I just have my soft bodies set up wrong, but I'm not sure how as I've tried to just follow tutorials.

This has been a helpful thread in the sense of the rigid square inside of the mesh deformer holding the soft body spheres. But theirs works so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:
[make soft bodies stay inside another soft body](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78955/make-soft-bodies-stay-inside-another-soft-body)

Here is the blend.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after testing it out a bit more, I realized it had to do with how I set up the cube. I removed the rigid body physics, kept the collision physics and decreased both the inner and outer thicknesses. That stopped it from pushing the balls together.